# Codeigniter subqueries

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Was looking for some help and found some but nothing for when the FROM also is a subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
    ( SELECT tc.*, 
             ( SELECT status FROM test_case_executions tce 
                   WHERE tce.test_case_id = tc.id 
                   ORDER BY tce.execution_date DESC, tce.id DESC LIMIT 1 
             ) AS last_status FROM test_cases tc 
    ) a 
WHERE a.last_status = '$status'
```

Is there a way in CI to just use this and execute it or can someone help me write this in the way CI wants it? Thanks

Comment: $this->db->query() function

Comment: Also see [db->query()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: There is [codeigniter subquery](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Subqueries) also. But its little bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need can really be found [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html), as mentioned in above comments. Just to get you started, here's how you could do it:

```
$this->db->query("
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM (  SELECT tc.*,
        (   SELECT status
            FROM test_case_executions AS tce 
            WHERE tce.test_case_id = tc.id 
            ORDER BY tce.execution_date DESC, tce.id DESC
            LIMIT 1) AS last_status
        FROM test_cases AS tc 
    ) AS a 
WHERE a.last_status = ?
", array($status));
```

Basicly this is what the comments are saying. What makes this more "CI convenient" than simple `mysql_query` etc. is that you're escaping passed values to free yourself from errors and sql injections. Note the last part `?` and the second parameter `array($status)`. I also styled this query to be a bit easier on the eye (imo).

You might think "But I wanna use Active Records! D:", however more advanced stuff requires you to leave the comfort zone. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I fine with going back to a move conventional way of doing it. Truth of the matter I still have not even gotten to the more difficult SQL queries. Thaanks